# How to add a span tag to a certain custom menu link in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to figure out how to add a span tag to a certain menu link in a custom menu. I only need it on one link within the custom menu links. Guessing a preprocess function and tried `theme_menu_item_link()` with no luck, didn't appear it was getting called at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer! Needed to use `theme_menu_link()`:

```
function theme_menu_link(array $variables) {
    $element = $variables['element'];
    $sub_menu = '';

    if ($element['#below']) {
        $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
    }

    $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
    return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7

There I can find the item I'm looking for and adjust it accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

Find the solution below.

Note that if you're using [Superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish) module, `theme_menu_link()` won't work in this case, so use `theme_superfish_menu_item_link` instead.

**Drupal 7**

```
/*
 * Implements theme_menu_link().
 */
 function THEME_menu_link(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }

  $element['#localized_options']['html'] = TRUE;
  $linktext = '<span class="tab-inner">' . $element['#title'] . '</span>';

  $output = l($linktext, $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

**Drupal 7 (with Superfish)**

```
/*
 * Implements theme_superfish_menu_item_link().
 *  Theme a superfish menu item link,
 *  to override menu item to insert span tags
 */
function THEME_superfish_menu_item_link(array $variables) {
  $menu_item = $variables['menu_item'];
  $link_options = $variables['link_options'] + array('html' => TRUE);
  $linktext = '<span class="tab-inner">' . $menu_item['link']['title'] . '</span>';
  return l($linktext, $menu_item['link']['link_path'], $link_options);
}
```

After defining above hooks, clear your caches to rebuild theme registry.

If above won't work, as suggested by [@weaveoftheride](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477629/how-to-add-a-span-tag-to-a-certain-custom-menu-link-in-drupal-7/22349886?noredirect=1#comment70392201_22349886), make sure to enable *Use a theme function for hyperlinks* and *Use a theme function for menu items* in the settings. Normally these should be enabled by default.

**Drupal 6** (just for reference)

```
/*
 * Implements theme_menu_item_link().
 */
function THEME_menu_item_link($link) {
  if (empty($link['localized_options'])) {
    $link['localized_options'] = array();
  }
  $link['localized_options'] += array('html'=>true);
  return l('<span>'.$link['title'].'</span>', $link['href'], $link['localized_options']);
}
```

---

<sup>Note: Don't forget to replace `THEME` with your machine name of your theme in all above code.</sup>

Comment: This isn't working for me. This hook isn't being found. It is in my template.php file.

Comment: @weaveoftheride Check the function name, e.g. `THEMENAME_menu_link` and clear your caches to reload registry.

Comment: I'm using Superfish so I should use theme_superfish_menu_item_link I think? Also my menu is in a block. Do that make any difference?  function nph_superfish_menu_item_link($variables) {
  dpm("BLAH");
  $menu_item = $variables['menu_item'];
  $link_options = $variables['link_options'];
  return l($menu_item['link']['title'], $menu_item['link']['href'], $link_options);
}

Comment: @weaveoftheride Replace `theme` with your machine name of your theme (so `nph`), so `nph_superfish_menu_item_link` should work. Otherwise I'm not sure why it wouldn't.

Comment: @weaveoftheride See: [`theme_superfish_menu_item_link`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/superfish/tree/superfish.module?h=7.x-1.x#n2167) in superfish.module, if you've this function, then problem with overriding this could be a caching issue. Otherwise maybe it's worth to ask another question.

Comment: OMG I can't believe it you have to enable - Use a theme function for hyperlinks and  Use a theme function for menu items in the settings even though it says (Default: enabled). I didn't realise this settings existed and it is confusing that it says enabled by default because I presumed that means without being checked- most probably my fault, been staring at it for too long.